# Angles can be congruent but not equal?

Tags: geometry

How could  ‘two angles cannot be equal, but two angles can be congruent? ‘ My understanding was if a shape is congruent then it would be equal in size and shape. If two angles are congruent, how could they not be equal?

Comment: you should give more of the quote, and say exactly what the source is

Comment: If measure of angle 1=32 and measure of angle 2=32, measure of angle 1 is equal to measure of angle 2, but angle one is not equal to angle two?

Comment: Was this book in English?

Comment: I think this is just a declaration of language convention by some author. We (initially) reserve the equals sign for equality of numbers or functions. Angles are a bit more abstract and I guess the author didn't like to call congruent angles equal.

Comment: If you consider an angle to be a figure in a plane (or in space) that has an angular measure associated with it, then an angle is a set of points and you can have many different sets of points that have the same angular measure. Different sets are not equal. This may be a definition found in some pre-university textbooks; at least I think I recall something like this. I think it's more common to regard "angle" as the angular measure itself, so "measure of angle 1" is a redundant phrase. The fact that you have seen the phrase "measure of angle 1" suggests something about your textbook.

Comment: To actually answer this question we'd need to see exactly how "angle" is defined, word for word. Citing the exact source might also help someone identify what definition it uses.

Comment: Just an idea: $1 \ne 1+2\pi$ but $1$ is congruent with $1+2\pi$?

Answer (score 1):

I’ll just say it: in typical usage, angle refers to the magnitude of the angle, and angles of the same magnitude are certainly equal. Congruence typically means a figure or shape is identical - each corresponding part is the same. If two line segments meet at an angle and the segments and angles are equal then you have congruence. As if two congruent triangles had a side subtracted. You would typically not bother saying rays meeting at identical angles are congruent, though it would be true. Unless your book has some explicit statement (and explanation) to the contrary, the above would be a standard Euclidean view.

Comment: Congruency in geometry means same shape, same size, same angles, but translated and/or rotatet **and/or mirrored**. That is why congruent angles in a triangle are not the same, $\alpha$ of triangle 1 is (if mirrored) $-\alpha$ in the congruent counterpart.

Comment: I disagree. Congruence is captured by the idea that figures/objects could be exactly superposed, including the ability to pick up and flip the construct. Otherwise Euclid I.4 (SAS) does not work - "angles contained by the equal straight lines equal". Thinking of an angle as negative is pulling in ideas from trig and trig functions that developed hundreds to thousands of years after geometric congruence was defined, and these ideas are not necessary or helpful to the many areas of geometry in which negative length or negative angles have no place.

Comment: If you like, I suppose you could say negative angles were lurking all along, but that Euclid's Postulate 4: "all right angles are equal to one another" let us convert the negative to positives, and we simply only talked about angles in the positive sense. But I don't think that's really the spirit of the postulate, and I don't think negative angles in typical constructs are a particularly helpful way to think about it, there is no need for it.

Comment: The question in OP is: _"If two angles are congruent, how could they not be equal?"_ and you disagree my attempt at explanation. As well I'm not convinced by your statement in length. Let me try again. A triangle with corners $ABC$ is mirrored to form a congruent triangle $A'B'C'$. Stepping around the first one from A to B to C and back to A and then do the same with the mirrored, from A' to B' to C' and back to A', you circled in different rotations (what is BTW a quick test to which side you look), and this change in sense of rotation does not affect the angles?

Comment: I bracketed my answer with the words typically and Euclidian. In Euclidean geometry, there was no reference frame or coordinate system for comparing figures and all angles were/are treated as positive quantities. To have these ideas of negative angles as compared to positive, you need a coordinate system or framework, which would date to Fermat or Descartes around 1600. To have the isometry/set theoretic definitions now mentioned, you're post-1850. The answer to the OP's specific question will depend on the text/era of text. The idea of equality upon superposition is the throughline of it all.

Answer (score 1):

If two angles are congruent, their measures are equal.  It's like saying two twins are identical and their heights are the same.  We don't say the twins are the same or equal, we just use a different word in that context.

Answer (score 0):

In most modern textbooks of Geometry, figures are defined as **sets of points**. And two sets are equal only if they have the same elements, i.e. two figures are equal only if they are made of **the same points**.

Congruence, instead, is a relation between figures obeying some axioms. Two congruent figures needn't be equal.